# Compile errors after update to xcode 4.2 and ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a project that has been running great on xcode 4, I updated to 4.2 and ios5 and now it wont compile!
I get:

```
Ld "build/Debug-iphoneos/Send Video.app/Send Video" normal armv7
cd "/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk "-L/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp/build/Debug-iphoneos" "-L/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp/SharedMomentsApp" "-L/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp" "-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/usr/lib" "-F/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp/build/Debug-iphoneos" -filelist "/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp/build/SharedMomentsApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/SharedMomentsApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Send Video.LinkFileList" -dead_strip /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -lz -lxml2.2 -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework QuartzCore -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MediaPlayer -framework MobileCoreServices -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o "/Volumes/Untitled 1/iOS/projects/SharedMomentsApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/Send Video.app/Send Video"
```

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

Anyone else have this sort of issue before?

Comment: You need to post the actual error message(s)

Comment: This is all it shows in my console.  How can I get more info?

Comment: When it fails it's trying to link. Have you tried `clean` in xcode already?

Comment: Yes, several times.  How can i tell what link is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the derived data:
Go to Organizer and select Projects at top. There's a Delete button to the right of the "Derived Data" item.

Comment: No such luck for me... I fixed all the warnings in my project after upgrading to the 5.0 SDK, replaced all the linked libraries with the latest versions, etc. I've tried cleaning, deleting derived data, etc. but I still get this mystical linker error.